# Match lines containing even numbers with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I am doing a series of questions regarding grep and I have gotten stuck on trying to match lines containing even numbers in any way (so, it should match `'hello22 23'`, `'8'`, `'2222 2999 1'`, `'hello2hello9'`, etc.)

The problem is that, while I managed to match all of those cases, I cannot find a way to match cases in which the line either contains exclusively an even number or it's the last occurrence before an EOL (`'22'`, `'hello8'`, anything that ends with a number which should match).

So far, this is what I'm using:

```
grep -P '((.)*[02468][^0-9](.)*)'
```

The above matches anything followed by an even number with no numbers whatsoever after it, followed by anything else.

I have tried playing with the `'$'` regex which should match it, with no effect. Could it be maybe that grep isn't detecting my EOLs properly?

Comment: Seems like `22` and `hello8` are subsets of the logic described in the first paragraph. I guess I don't understand the requirements. You just want lines that contain an even number, yes?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I am confusing since this is not my mother tongue. The problem is that the expression I have so far doesn't seem to match lines with an even number followed by an EOL

Comment: Gotcha. The reason it doesn't match is that `[^0-9]` is required to follow the even number. Oh, I think I see the problem--you're trying to not match lines like `23` which have an even _digit_ but the number it's a part of is not even, correct?

Comment: Maybe `grep -E '(^|[^0-9])[0-9]*[02468]($|[^0-9])'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're after--you want to avoid lines that may contain even digits but the numbers they comprise are all not even. Examples include `3`, `23`, `a23`, `23a`, `3a49`. You want to match lines that have at least one even number: `2`, `22`, `32`, `a32`, `32a`, `45a5bb44`, etc.

The pattern `grep -P '[02468](?=\D|$)'` ensures at least one even digit is present that's followed by EOL or a non-digit using a lookahead and should fit your requirements.

```
$ cat test.txt
3
23
a23
23a
3a49
2
22
32
a32
32a
45a5bb44
$ grep -P '[02468](?=\D|$)' test.txt
2
22
32
a32
32a
45a5bb44
```

Comment: Wow, now that's advanced, thanks! Indeed that was what I was looking for, I will have to take a look at lookaheads!

Comment: @Lightsong You'd better use `grep -E '[02468]([^0-9]|$)'`, or, if you want to use a PCRE expression, use a more efficient - since there is no alternation in the lookahead - `grep -P '[02468](?!\d)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good call. Mind if I steal `(?!\d)` as an edit?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I will have a look at both